# LINQ using .ToDictionary without .Select

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> clauses = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

where the clauses are like this:

```
"A|B" - "some text"
"A|D|E" - "some text"
"G" - "some text"
"E|A" - "some text"
...
```

and I want to populate the dictionary below:

```
Dictionary<string, int> columnsBitMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

where the `string` values are the unique `letters` of the first dictionary strings and `int` values are calculated by math formula.

I have the following which is working perfectly:

```
columnsBitMap = String.Join("|", clauses.Select(clause => clause).Select(clause => clause.Key)).Split('|')
                .Distinct().OrderBy(column => column)
                -- can I remove the next Select ?
                .Select((column, index) => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(column, index))
                .ToDictionary(column => column.Key, column => Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, column.Value)));
```

but I am wondering if this could be simplified removing the `.Select` part?

---

The output should be like this:

```
A 1
B 2
D 4
E 8
G 16
```

Comment: i assume the provided input is pretty clear, could you pls provide an equivalent example of the desired output? I am not sure if i get the description correctly...thx

Comment: @nozzleman I have added the outpu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bit is completely superfluous:

```
.Select(clause => clause)
```

Just remove it and the rest should work fine.

---

I dont see much reason to get rid of the part

```
.Select((column, index) => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(column, index))
```

But if you're against using a `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` you could just make it an anonymous object

```
.Select((column, index) => new{ Key = column, Value = index })
```

But there's not a great amount of difference.

---

I approached your requirement in a slightly different way:

```
var result = clauses.SelectMany(clause => clause.Key.Split('|'))
            .Distinct().OrderBy(column => column)
            .Select((column, index) => new {Key=column,Value=index})
            .ToDictionary(column => column.Key, column => Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, column.Value)));
```

Working example with your test case: http://rextester.com/PWC41147